# Null pointer exception when trying to send and modify data to another stage in java fx

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, grid

hi Im new to the java Im trying to make a game so I made cell class and a grid class to show the grid u can successfully add stars walls or smileys to the grid however when I try to send the grid to the actual gamepage for the player to play I get null pointer exception as if there is no cell in the grid that user entered the smileys and so on I have worked on this problem for days please help
note that **entry mouse gesture class** and **game mouse gesture** are the same because Im trying to solve this problem and then work in details

this is the cell class

```
package sample.CellandGrid;

import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class cell extends StackPane {

    int column;
    int row;
    boolean star;
    boolean wall;
    String player;

    public cell(int column, int row,boolean star,boolean wall,String player) {

        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
        this.star=star;
        this.wall = wall;
        this.player= player;

        getStyleClass().add("cell");

//          Label label = new Label(this.toString());
//
//          getChildren().add(label);

        setOpacity(0.9);
    }
    public void makeStar(){
        getStyleClass().remove("cell-highlight");
        getStyleClass().add("cell-star-highlight");
    }
    public void removeStar(){
        getStyleClass().remove("cell-star-highlight");
        getStyleClass().add("cell");
    }
    public void makewall(){
        getStyleClass().remove("cell-highlight");
        getStyleClass().add("cell-wall-highlight");
    }
    public void removeWall(){
        getStyleClass().remove("cell-wall-highlight");
        getStyleClass().add("cell");
    }
    public void smileyone(){
        getStyleClass().remove("cell");
        getStyleClass().add("cell-smiley1-highlight");
    }
    public void removeSmileyone(){
        getStyleClass().remove("cell-smiley1-highlight");
        getStyleClass().add("cell");
    }
    public void smileytwo(){
        getStyleClass().remove("cell");
        getStyleClass().add("cell-smiley2-highlight");
    }
    public void removeSmileytwo(){
        getStyleClass().remove("cell-smiley2-highlight");
        getStyleClass().add("cell");
    }


    public void highlight() {
        // ensure the style is only once in the style list
        getStyleClass().remove("cell-highlight");

        // add style
        getStyleClass().add("cell-highlight");
    }

    public void unhighlight() {
        getStyleClass().remove("cell-star-highlight");
    }

    public void hoverHighlight() {
        // ensure the style is only once in the style list
        getStyleClass().remove("cell-hover-highlight");

        // add style
        getStyleClass().add("cell-hover-highlight");
    }

    public void hoverUnhighlight() {
        getStyleClass().remove("cell-hover-highlight");
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.column + "/" + this.row;
    }
}
```

this is the grid class

```
package sample.CellandGrid;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class grid extends Pane {

    int rows;
    int columns;

    double width;
    double height;

    boolean star;
    boolean wall;

    cell [][] cells;

    public grid( int columns, int rows, double width, double height,boolean star,boolean wall) {

        this.columns = columns;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.star = star;
        this.wall = wall;

        cells = new cell[rows][columns];

    }

    /**
     * Add cell to array and to the UI.
     */
    public void add(cell cell, int column, int row) {

        cells[row][column] = cell;

        double w = width / columns;
        double h = height / rows;
        double x = w * column;
        double y = h * row;

        cell.setLayoutX(x);
        cell.setLayoutY(y);
        cell.setPrefWidth(w);
        cell.setPrefHeight(h);

        getChildren().add(cell);

    }

    public cell getCell(int column, int row) {
        return cells[row][column];
    }

    /**
     * Unhighlight all cells
     */
    public void unhighlight() {
        for( int row=0; row < rows; row++) {
            for( int col=0; col < columns; col++) {
                cells[row][col].unhighlight();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the entrymouse gestue class

```
package sample.CellandGrid;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.PickResult;
import sample.UserEnteredGrid.userGrid;

public class entryMouseGesture {
        public void Paint( Node node) {


            // that's all there is needed for hovering, the other code is just for painting
            if( true) {
                node.hoverProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){

                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

                        System.out.println( observable + ": " + newValue);

                        if( newValue) {
                            ((cell) node).hoverHighlight();
                        } else {
                            ((cell) node).hoverUnhighlight();
                        }

                        for( String s: node.getStyleClass())
                            System.out.println( node + ":gooz " + s);
                    }

                });
            }

            node.setOnMousePressed( onMousePressedEventHandler);


        }

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = event -> {

            PickResult pick = event.getPickResult();
            Node node = pick.getIntersectedNode();
            outerloop :
            if (node instanceof cell) {
                cell cell = (cell) event.getSource();
                if(userGrid.button.compareTo("star")==0) {
                    if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                        cell.makeStar();
                        cell.star=true;
                        System.out.println("check"+cell.star);
                    } else if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                        cell.removeStar();
                        cell.star=false;
                        System.out.println("check"+cell.star);

                    }
                } else if(userGrid.button.compareTo("smiley1")==0) {

                    if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {

                        if(userGrid.hasFirstPlayer==true){
                            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                            //alert.setAlertType(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                            alert.setTitle("Warning");
                            alert.setHeaderText("ILLEGAL ACTION");
                            alert.setContentText("YOU HAVE PLACED THE FIRST PLAYER ALREADY!");
                            alert.showAndWait();
                            break outerloop;
                        }

                        cell.smileyone();
                        cell.player = "1";
                        userGrid.hasFirstPlayer=true;

                    } else if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                        if(cell.player.compareTo("1")==0){
                            userGrid.hasFirstPlayer=false;
                        }
                        cell.removeSmileyone();
                        cell.player = "";
                        System.out.println("s1check");
                    }

                }else if(userGrid.button.compareTo("smiley2")==0) {
                    if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                        if(userGrid.hasSecondPlayer==true){
                            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                            //alert.setAlertType(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
                            alert.setTitle("Warning");
                            alert.setHeaderText("ILLEGAL ACTION");
                            alert.setContentText("YOU HAVE PLACED THE Second PLAYER ALREADY!");
                            alert.showAndWait();
                            break outerloop;
                        }
                        cell.smileytwo();
                        cell.player = "2";
                        userGrid.hasSecondPlayer=true;
                    } else if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                        if(cell.player.compareTo("2")==0){
                            userGrid.hasSecondPlayer=false;
                        }
                        cell.removeSmileytwo();
                        cell.player = "";
                        System.out.println("s2check");

                    }
                }else if(userGrid.button.compareTo("wall")==0) {
                    if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                        cell.makewall();
                        cell.wall=true;
                    } else if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                        cell.removeWall();
                        cell.wall=false;
                        System.out.println("wall: "+cell.wall);

                    }
                }
            }

        };
        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = event -> {
        };

}
```

this is the game mouse gesture class

```
package sample.CellandGrid;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.PickResult;
import sample.UserEnteredGrid.userGrid;

public class gameMouseGesture {

    public void Paint( Node node) {


         //that's all there is needed for hovering, the other code is just for painting
        if( true) {
            node.hoverProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

                    System.out.println( observable + ": " + newValue);

                    if( newValue) {
                        ((cell) node).hoverHighlight();
                    } else {
                        ((cell) node).hoverUnhighlight();
                    }

                    for( String s: node.getStyleClass())
                        System.out.println( node + ":gooz " + s);
                }

            });
        }
        if (node instanceof cell){
            cell mycell =(cell) node;
            if (mycell.star==true){
                mycell.makeStar();
            }else if (mycell.wall==true){
                mycell.makewall();
            }else if (mycell.player=="1"){
                mycell.smileyone();
            }else if(mycell.player=="2"){
                mycell.smileytwo();
            }


        }



        node.setOnMousePressed( onMousePressedEventHandler);


    }

    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = event -> {

        PickResult pick = event.getPickResult();
        Node node = pick.getIntersectedNode();
        outerloop :
        if (node instanceof cell) {
            cell cell = (cell) event.getSource();
            System.out.println("checked");
        }

    };
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = event -> {
    };

}
```

this is the dimension page where user enters the height and width number of row and so on
dimension page controller

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.CellandGrid.grid;
import sample.Data.dataModel;
import sample.CellandGrid.grid;
import sample.CellandGrid.cell;
import sample.UserEnteredGrid.userGrid;

import java.io.IOException;



public class dimensionPageController {
    @FXML
    TextField GridWidth;
    @FXML
    TextField GridHeight;
    @FXML
    TextField row;
    @FXML
    TextField column;
    @FXML
    TextField name1;
    @FXML
    TextField name2;

    Parent root;
    Stage stage;

    //public static

    public void pageDimensions() throws IOException {
        int gHeight =Integer.parseInt(GridHeight.getText());
        int gWidth = Integer.parseInt(GridHeight.getText());
        int rrow = Integer.parseInt(row.getText());
        int ccolumn = Integer.parseInt(column.getText());
        dataModel.gridHeight=gHeight;
        dataModel.gridWidth=gWidth;
        dataModel.row=rrow;
        dataModel.column=ccolumn;
        //try {
        System.out.println("Dimension Happened");
        //System.out.println( gHeight);
        System.out.println("AIMING FOR GRID");
        userGrid grid = new userGrid();
        grid.start((Stage)row.getScene().getWindow());

//            try {
//                root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/GridInitializer.fxml"));
//                stage = (Stage) row.getScene().getWindow();
//                Scene scene = new Scene(root, DataModel.gridWidth, DataModel.gridHeight);
//                stage.setScene(scene);
//                stage.setTitle("please god ");
//                stage.show();
//            } catch (Exception e) {
//
//                System.out.println("grid initiakizer went wring /init.page controller");
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
//        }catch (Exception ex){
//            System.out.println("101");
//            ex.getCause();
//            System.out.println("101");
//        }
//
    }
}
```

dimension page fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane alignment="TOP_CENTER" hgap="10" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgb(38,38,38)"
          vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
          fx:controller="sample.dimensionPageController">

    <Label alignment="TOP_CENTER" style="-fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255);         -fx-font-size: 20;-fx-border-color: rgb(250,3,3);-fx-border-radius: 10" text=" FirstPageInitialization " GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />

    <Label style="-fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255);" text="Page Width: " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
    <TextField fx:id="GridWidth" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />

    <Label style="-fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255);" text="Page Height: " GridPane.columnIndex="1"
           GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
    <TextField fx:id="GridHeight" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3"  />

    <Label style="-fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255);" text="First player Name: " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
    <TextField fx:id="Name1" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />

    <Label style="-fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255);" text="Second player Name: " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
    <TextField fx:id="Name2" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />

    <Label style="-fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255);" text="rows: " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
    <TextField fx:id="row" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />

    <Label style="-fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255);" text="columns: " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
    <TextField fx:id="column" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />

    <Button fx:id="ok" alignment="CENTER" onMouseClicked="#pageDimensions" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="187.0" style="-fx-fill: rgb(255,255,255)" text="Save" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints />
        <ColumnConstraints />
        <ColumnConstraints />
        <ColumnConstraints />
        <ColumnConstraints />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
        <RowConstraints />
    </rowConstraints>

</GridPane>
```

this is the part when user sees the grid and places icons on it (svg path) 
usergrid class:

```
package sample.UserEnteredGrid;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.CellandGrid.grid;
import sample.CellandGrid.cell;
import sample.CellandGrid.grid;
import sample.Data.dataModel;
import sample.CellandGrid.entryMouseGesture;
import sample.gamePageGrid.gamePageGRID;


public class userGrid extends Application {
    int rows = dataModel.row;
    int columns = dataModel.column;
    double width = dataModel.gridWidth;
    double height = dataModel.gridHeight;

    public static String button = "";
    public static boolean hasFirstPlayer = false;
    public static boolean hasSecondPlayer=false;


    static cell savedGridCells [][];

    public static grid TransitGrid;
    grid grid = new grid( columns, rows, width, height,false,false);
    @FXML
    Button starButton;

    HBox joinedRoot;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            Parent root2;
            // create grid


             entryMouseGesture mg = new entryMouseGesture();

            // fill grid
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {

                    cell cell = new cell(column, row,false,false,"");

                    mg.Paint(cell);
                    //dataModel.datamodelCell[row][column]=cell;
                    grid.add(cell,column,row);

                }
            }

            root.getChildren().addAll(grid);
            root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(38,38,38)");
            root2= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("userGrid.fxml"));
            // create scene and stage
            joinedRoot = new HBox(root2,root);
            joinedRoot.setSpacing(10);
            System.out.println(root2.getLayoutX());
            joinedRoot.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(38,38,38)");
            Scene scene2 = new Scene(new VBox(root2,root) , width, height+110);
            scene2.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("userGrid.css").toExternalForm());

            primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
            primaryStage.show();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("tap");
            e.getCause();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @FXML
    public void star(){
        System.out.println("starshit");
        button="star";
    }
    @FXML
    public void smiley1(){
        System.out.println("s1shit");
        button="smiley1";
    }
    @FXML
    public void smiley2(){
        System.out.println("s2shit");
        button="smiley2";
    }
    @FXML
    public void wall(){
        System.out.println("wall shit");
        button="wall";
    }

    @FXML
    private BorderPane gamePageBorderPane;

    @FXML
    public void submit(){
        dataModel.dataModelGrid=grid;
        System.out.println("first check "+grid.getCell(1,1));
        System.out.println("check "+dataModel.dataModelGrid.getCell(1,1));
        System.out.println("game page happening");
         gamePageGRID gamePage = new gamePageGRID();
         gamePage.start(new Stage());

//        try {
//            Stage stagew;
//            Parent root;
//            stagew = (Stage) starButton.getScene().getWindow();
//            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("gamePage.fxml"));
//            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
//            stagew.setScene(scene);
//            stagew.setTitle("GAME WINDOW");
//
//            stagew.show();
//        }catch (Exception e){
//            System.out.println("ude");
//            e.getCause();
//            System.out.println("ude");
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

    }


}
```

user grid css

```
.cell{
    -fx-background-color: rgb(38,38,38);
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
}
.cell-highlight {
    -fx-background-color:derive(blue,0.9);
}
.cell-hover-highlight {
    -fx-background-color:derive(green,0.9);
}
.cell-star-highlight{

    /*-fx-background-color: derive(white,1%);*/
    /*-fx-shape:"M2,2 L8,2 L2,5 L8,5 L2,8 L8,8";*/

    -fx-shape: "M 100 0 L175 200 L0 75 L200 75 L25 200 Z" ;
    -fx-fill: derive(yellow,10%);
    -fx-background-color: derive(yellow,10%);

}
.cell-smiley1-highlight{
    -fx-shape: "M2 1 h1 v1 h1 v1 h-1 v1 h-1 v-1 h-1 v-1 h1 z";
    -fx-background-color: derive(red,10%);
    -fx-stroke: blue;
    -fx-stroke-width: 5
}
.cell-smiley2-highlight{
    -fx-background-color: derive(blue,10%);
    -fx-shape: "M2 1 h1 v1 h1 v1 h-1 v1 h-1 v-1 h-1 v-1 h1 z";
    -fx-background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    -fx-stroke: red;
    -fx-stroke-width: 5
}
.cell-wall-highlight{
    -fx-background-color: derive(white,1%);
    -fx-shape:"M2,2 L8,2 L2,5 L8,5 L2,8 L8,8";
}
.background{
    -fx-background-color: rgb(38,38,38);
}
```

user grid fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<?import sample.userGrid?>-->
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>


<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane hgap="5" stylesheets="@userGrid.css"
          xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
          fx:controller="sample.UserEnteredGrid.userGrid">
    <Label text="click on button Left-click to put the element Right-click to remove" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    <HBox spacing="10" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
        <Button fx:id="starButton" id="starButton-highlight" onMouseClicked="#star" text="Star" ></Button>
        <Button fx:id="wallButton" id="wallButton-highlight" onMouseClicked="#wall" text="Wall" ></Button>
        <Button fx:id="smiley1Button" id="smiley1Button-highlight" onMouseClicked="#smiley1" text="smiley1" ></Button>
        <Button fx:id="smiley2Button" id="smiley2Button-highlight" onMouseClicked="#smiley2" text="smiley2" ></Button>
        <Button fx:id="submit" text="SUBMIT" onMouseClicked="#submit"/>
    </HBox>


</GridPane>
```

and this is the game page where user gets to play
gamepage class

```
package sample.gamePageGrid;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sample.CellandGrid.gameMouseGesture;
import sample.CellandGrid.grid;
import sample.CellandGrid.cell;
import sample.CellandGrid.grid;
import sample.Data.dataModel;
import sample.UserEnteredGrid.userGrid;


// import static sample.dimensionPageController.grid;


public class gamePageGRID extends Application{

    int rows = dataModel.row;
    int columns = dataModel.column;
    double width = dataModel.gridWidth;
    double height = dataModel.gridHeight;

    public static String button = "";
    public static boolean hasFirstPlayer = false;
    public static boolean hasSecondPlayer=false;


    static cell savedGridCells [][];

    static grid TransitGrid;
    grid mygrid = new grid( columns, rows, width, height,false,false);
    @FXML
    Button starButton;

    HBox joinedRoot;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane ggridRoot =new StackPane();

        gameMouseGesture mg = new gameMouseGesture();

        System.out.println("OKAY GAME PAGE");

        for (int row=0;row<rows;row++){
            for (int column=0;column<columns;columns++){
                cell mycell=(cell) dataModel.dataModelGrid.getCell(column,row);
                mg.Paint(mycell);
                mygrid.add(mycell,column,row);

            }
        }
        ggridRoot.getChildren().addAll(mygrid);
        Scene gameScene = new Scene(ggridRoot);
        gameScene.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("gameGrid.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(gameScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

here is the data model

```
package sample.Data;
import sample.CellandGrid.*;
public class dataModel {
    public static int gridHeight;
    public static int gridWidth;
    public static String name1;
    public static String name2;
    public static int row;
    public static int column;
    public static grid dataModelGrid;

}
```

here is the stack trace of the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.CellandGrid.gameMouseGesture.Paint(gameMouseGesture.java:19)
    at sample.gamePageGrid.gamePageGRID.start(gamePageGRID.java:57)
    at sample.UserEnteredGrid.userGrid.submit(userGrid.java:123)
    ... 41 more
```

and my project structure looks like this

[image]

Comment: Java should give you the line number of the error, of course we can't see the line numbers here so you should use the error line number to somehow tell us exactly where in your code the error is happening

Comment: @Nerdsie I have add the part of the stack trace error happens because there is no cell so node.hoverpropery cannot happen;      at the usergrid class submit button I have added to sout check which returns null, so only conclusion is game Grid have received a grid of null cell if any at all so no change can be implemented on cell`s mouse gesture

Comment: So why not replace `if (true)` (which is completely pointless anyway) with `if (node != null)`? Also, please follow standard [Java naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). It's virtually impossible to read and understand your code with the class and variable names you have chosen.

Comment: @James_D of course I will take that into account, and I apologize for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have finally found the Answer 
I apologize to anyone who spent time reviewing my question 
for the problem is solely caused by substantial amount of ignorance on my part and me not following **Java naming conventions** and of no significant learning value

 
the problem was caused by the second for loop in the game page in which I added to the boundary in stead of the variable 

** let this be a fine example to always follow JAVA NAMING CONVENTION or else you`ll spend days try to find a needle in a hay stack **

I have rectified the code

```
  for (int row=0;row<rows;row++){
            for (int column=0;column<columns;column++){
                cell mycell=(cell) dataModel.dataModelGrid.getCell(column,row);
                mg.Paint(mycell);
                mygrid.add(mycell,column,row);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell cell = new cell(column, row, false ,false, "");
```

The type and the object have the same name, it looks like a very bad idea to me.
Name the class "Cell" and the object "cell" and tell me if it works better.

```
Cell cell = new Cell(column, row, false ,false, "");
```

The declaration of the class becomes:

```
public class Cell extends StackPane {
}
```

It's constructor becomes:

```
public Cell(int column, int row, boolean star, boolean wall, String player) {
}
```

By convention, all class names should start by an upper letter, and all objects by a lower letter.

Comment: While good advice (and there is a whole lot that could be done in a code review of the OP's post), this doesn't actually answer the question, because it won't solve the Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Don't you think it could lead to the error? mg.Paint(cell); seems to be interpreted as mg.Paint(null); Also I would have commented by I can't, I'm under 50 rep. Sorry if it was not appropriate.

Comment: No, it couldn't lead to the error. What you name the variable/class has nothing at all to do with its value.

Comment: @James_D while checking for the nodes not being null as you commented earlier actually makes the new window come up however the problem of the contents being null still exists and I cant find what is causing it

Comment: @FabienGaubert  I appreciate the effort and consideration you have put into my code and I will take your advices into account unfortunately the problem remains... thanks anyway